# How do I create instances of a Ruby class from data in an array?

Tags: ruby

I've got an array of strings. Example:

```
array = [ "mmaciel:x:23585:591:mmaciel:/students/mmaciel:/bin/bash\n", 
          "nhalvors:x:20943:565:nhalvors:/students/nhalvors:/bin/bash\n", 
          "orodrigu:x:28260:576:orodrigu:/students/orodrigu:/bin/bash\n" ]
```

And I want to populate class Student:

```
class Student
  attr_accessor :user_name, :password, :uid, :gid,
                :gcos_field, :directory, :shell
  attr_reader :count

  def initialize(data)
    @user_name,@password,@uid,@gid,@gcos_field,@directory,@shell = data
    @@count = defined?(@@count) ? @@count += 1 : 1

  end
end
```

If it's just one element of the array, it's simple to me. Simply:

```
data = "dputnam:x:4185:208:Douglas Vernon Putnam:/users/dputnam:/bin/bash".split(':')
s1 = Student.new(data)
```

But since I have an array of dozens of elements, it becomes much more complicated for me. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use `Array#map` method for this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
array = [ "mmaciel:x:23585:591:mmaciel:/students/mmaciel:/bin/bash\n", 
          "nhalvors:x:20943:565:nhalvors:/students/nhalvors:/bin/bash\n", 
          "orodrigu:x:28260:576:orodrigu:/students/orodrigu:/bin/bash\n" ]
students = array.map { |line| Student.new(line.chomp.split(":")) }
```

Then `students` would be a collection of students

Comment: +1.. exactly what I asked OP.. to do.. This is the way to do.